# Is it possible to initialize a constexpr std::array from a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

Im trying to make an array that should be `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0}` and i would like to do simething like this:

```
constexpr std::array<int, 9> getFinalTable(){
    std::array<int, 9> result{};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 9 - 1; ++i) 
        result[i] = i + 1;
    result.back() = 0;
    return result;
}
```

But Visual Studio stops me at type time here:

```
 constexpr std::array<int, 9> final_table = getFinalTable();
```

Is it possible to do what i'm trying to do? (I would like to have it like this so i can change the size of the `Table` in anytime i want and still works).

Comment: `back` is only constexpr since c++17 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/back so that may be your issue. that code compiles fine for me with gcc10 and -std=c++2a

Comment: Maybe that means that this only works for `c++20`? (using that flags) If i comment that line if get the error in the line of the declaration of `final table`.

Comment: it compiles with c++17 as well. which compiler are you using?

Comment: @FranzKafka: "*stops me at type time here*" ... what does "type time" mean? What compile error do you get?

Comment: @NicolBolas at the moment i type it, i'm using Visual Studio. I get `expresion must have constant value`

Comment: @UnforeseenPrincess you right, i was using Visual Studio most new version and MinGW Distro (GCC 9.2.0) and i guess i will activate `-std=c++17`, (yes, it does work in c++17).

Comment: @FranzKafka: "*at the moment i type it*" And what happens when you *really* compile it, rather than relying on what the IDE tells you? Also, are you compiling it as C++17? Because `std::array` is not usefully `constexpr` in C++14.

Comment: Actually, i get exactly that message! But i already fixed it activating c++17, you were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It'll correctly work in `-std=c++17` (C++17 and above) compilation.**

From the first answer to this question, the comment from the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62976329/is-it-possible-to-initialize-a-constexpr-stdarray-from-a-constexpr-function#comment111366313_62976375) indicates that the line:

```
result.back() = 0;
```

Won't let the compiler compile it due to:

```
main.cpp: In function 'constexpr std::array<int, 9> getFinalTable()':
main.cpp:9:21: error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type& std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::back() [with _Tp = int; long long unsigned int _Nm = 9; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::reference = int&; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type = int]'
    9 |         result.back() = 0;
      |
```

After removing it, the relevant program should look something like:

```
const int size = 9;

constexpr std::array<int, size> getFinalTable() {
    std::array<int, size> result{};
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) 
        result[i] = i + 1;
//  result.back() = 0;

    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    const std::array<int, size> final_table = getFinalTable();
}
```