# Modern C++ how to create constexpr array of power of 10?

Tags: c++, arrays, static, c++17, constexpr

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class FastFtoa {
public:

static inline constexpr double __inv_pow_10[] = {
  1.0,                                      // 0
  0.1f,                                      // 1
  0.01,                                     // 2
  0.001,                                    // 3
  0.0001,                                   // 4
  0.00001,                                  // 5
  0.000001,                                 // 6
  0.0000001,                                // 7
  0.00000001,                               // 8
  0.000000001,                              // 9
  0.0000000001,                             // 10
  0.00000000001,                            // 11
  0.000000000001,                           // 12
  0.0000000000001,                          // 13
  0.00000000000001,                         // 14
  0.000000000000001,                        // 15
  0.0000000000000001,                       // 16
  0.00000000000000001,                      // 17
  0.000000000000000001,                     // 18
  0.0000000000000000001,                    // 19
  0.00000000000000000001,                   // 20
  0.000000000000000000001,                  // 21
  0.0000000000000000000001,                 // 22
  0.00000000000000000000001,                // 23
  0.000000000000000000000001,               // 24
  0.0000000000000000000000001,              // 25
  0.00000000000000000000000001,             // 26
  0.000000000000000000000000001,            // 27
  0.0000000000000000000000000001,           // 28
  0.00000000000000000000000000001,          // 29
  0.000000000000000000000000000001,         // 30
  0.0000000000000000000000000000001,        // 31
  0.00000000000000000000000000000001,       // 32
  0.000000000000000000000000000000001,      // 33
  0.0000000000000000000000000000000001,     // 34
  0.00000000000000000000000000000000001,    // 35
  0.000000000000000000000000000000000001,   // 36
  0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001, // 37
  0.000000000000000000000000000000000000001 // 38

};

static inline constexpr double __pos_pow_10[] = {
  1.0,                                      // 0
  10.0,                                     // 1
  100.0,                                    // 2
  1000.0,                                   // 3
  10000.0,                                  // 4
  100000.0,                                 // 5
  1000000.0,                                // 6
  10000000.0,                               // 7
  100000000.0,                              // 8
  1000000000.0,                             // 9
  10000000000.0,                            // 10
  100000000000.0,                           // 11
  1000000000000.0,                          // 12
  10000000000000.0,                         // 13
  100000000000000.0,                        // 14
  1000000000000000.0,                       // 15
  10000000000000000.0,                      // 16
  100000000000000000.0,                     // 17
  1000000000000000000.0,                    // 18
  10000000000000000000.0,                   // 19
  100000000000000000000.0,                  // 20
  1000000000000000000000.0,                 // 21
  10000000000000000000000.0,                // 22
  100000000000000000000000.0,               // 23
  1000000000000000000000000.0,              // 24
  10000000000000000000000000.0,             // 25
  100000000000000000000000000.0,            // 26
  1000000000000000000000000000.0,           // 27
  10000000000000000000000000000.0,          // 28
  100000000000000000000000000000.0,         // 29
  1000000000000000000000000000000.0,        // 30
  10000000000000000000000000000000.0,       // 31
  100000000000000000000000000000000.0,      // 32
  1000000000000000000000000000000000.0,     // 33
  10000000000000000000000000000000000.0,    // 34
  100000000000000000000000000000000000.0,   // 35
  1000000000000000000000000000000000000.0,  // 36
  10000000000000000000000000000000000000.0, // 37
  100000000000000000000000000000000000000.0 // 38
};

};

int main()
{
    cout << FastFtoa::__inv_pow_10[37] << " " << FastFtoa::__pos_pow_10[37] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I need to create `constexpr` array of `10^x` and `10^-x`, for x in range <s>-64..64</s> `-38..38`. It's for fast float to string conversion. It also needs to be inside a static class (all functions are public static).

It's possible to create them manually like in the code above, but it doesn't look good. Not to mention the full `float64` range is `10^308`, and that will be a very ugly code if it's done manually.

In C++17/20, what's the proper way to do this?

Comment: A better question is this: why do you think you need it? A float can't even store some of those numbers exactly.

Comment: Actually I don't need more than 18 digits in my actual use case. I  just want to use `std::array` or similar so the code looks better. The mention to `10^308` is purely theoretical

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62976329/is-it-possible-to-initialize-a-constexpr-stdarray-from-a-constexpr-function) example of initializing a constexpr std::array

Comment: Identifiers containing a double underscore are reserved for the implementation. There are plenty of others to choose from.

Comment: You are missing another problem - a limitation of floating point. For a `float`  (32bit) biggest integer power of 10 you can represent is 10^10, for  64bit `double` it's 10^22. 10^308 is a full range, but not all values can be represnted correctly.  Comparing (I suppose that's the end goal of this) float to a suboptimal integer is also a tricky thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use an unnamed lambda to initialize the `constexpr std::array` to reduce namespace clutter. `inline` is redundant for static constexprs.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class FastFtoa {
public:
    static constexpr size_t N{39};
    static constexpr std::array<float, N> _pos_pow_10 = []() {
        std::array<float, N> x{1};
        for (size_t i = 1; i < N; i++)
            x[i] = 10*x[i-1];
        return x;
    }();
    static constexpr std::array<float, N> _inv_pow_10 = []() {
        std::array<float, N> x{1};
        for (size_t i = 1; i < N; i++)
            x[i] = .1f * x[i - 1];
        return x;
    }();
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << FastFtoa::_pos_pow_10[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << FastFtoa::_pos_pow_10[38] << '\n';
    std::cout << FastFtoa::_inv_pow_10[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << FastFtoa::_inv_pow_10[38] << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1
1e+38
1
1e-38
```

Comment: This one is closest to the code example in the question, and is the most simple. But the naming is reversed (`inv_pow_10` gives `10^x` instead of `10^-x`). Can you edit the answer then I'll mark the question as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>


template<typename T, T... ints>
constexpr auto sequence1(std::integer_sequence<T, ints...>)
{
    return std::array{std::pow(10L, ints)...};
}

template<typename T, T... ints>
constexpr auto sequence2(std::integer_sequence<T, ints...>)
{
    return std::array{(1/std::pow(10L, ints))...};
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto my_arr1 = sequence1(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, 20>{});
    constexpr auto my_arr2 = sequence2(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, 20>{});
    std::cout << my_arr1[5] << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_arr2[5] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Concat stuff is unneeded [Demo][https://godbolt.org/z/n3EKd9hds). Require implementation of `constexpr` `pow` anyway...

Comment: Great~, that will be easy and straight forward

Comment: Isn't that an array of int ? Can you edit it to return array of float to match the question better? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it is not an array of int, because the std::power() returns "float' or "double" but not "int".   But anyway, changed my answer based on the great optimization by Jarod42.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the fact that std::array is constexpr. And as long as you have calculations that can be done at compile time you can fill that array with calculated values.

In this example : `make_pow_10_map` makes a map of powers of 10. Simply dividing 1.0f by 10.f in a loop, and multiplying 1.0f by 10.f in another loop. All the values are stored in one array (you can easiliy do the same for 2 arrays).

Then this compile time array is used in a simple lookup function that returns precalculated values.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template<std::size_t N>
static constexpr auto make_pow_10_map()
{
    std::array<float, (2 * N)> values{};
    
    float value{ 1.0 };
    
    for (std::size_t n = (N-1); n > 0ul; --n)
    {
        values[n] = value;
        value /= 10.0f;
    }
    values[0] = value;
    
    value = 1.0;
    for (std::size_t n = (N-1); n < 2*N; ++n)
    {
        values[n] = value;
        value *= 10.0f;
    }

    return values;
}

float pow_10(int n)
{
    constexpr std::size_t N{37ul};
    static constexpr auto powers_of_10 = make_pow_10_map<N>();
    int limit = N;

    if ((n < -limit) || (n > limit)) throw std::invalid_argument{"index out of range"};

    std::size_t index = (powers_of_10.size() / 2ul) + n - 1ul;
    return powers_of_10[index];
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << pow_10(-3) << "\n";
    std::cout << pow_10(0) << "\n";
    std::cout << pow_10(6) << "\n";
    std::cout << pow_10(10) << "\n";
    std::cout << pow_10(11) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```